# How to get CST Timezone for Django DateTimefield column

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, sqlalchemy, timezone

I want to update existing DB data and it should update the "DateTimeStamp" field in database with current time (Central time).

**DB Table configuration :**
DateTimeStamp field is having default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

**Django setting.py configuration :**
TIME_ZONE = 'US/Central'

**Django models.py configuration :**
DateTimeStamp = models.DateTimeField()

**Django views.py :**
dt = datetime.now().astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Central'))

when I check "dt", it shows date in Central only, but when I update the table, it is not reflecting in Central time

table.objects.filter(col1=col1).update(col2=col2,col3=col3,DateTimeStamp=dt)

dt = 2022-03-14 07:53:19
database field got updated with 2022-03-14 23:23:19

Can someone please assist me what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by changing field type in models.py file.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved with additional supporting information.

It will probably be very helpful to include the field type (and arguments) you selected finally.

Comment: I had used "DateTimeStamp = models.TextField()" and it worked as expected during update but while inserting new record, it was considering "00:00:00 00:00:00".... So, needed to go with timedelta approach....

models.py : DateTimeStamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
views.py : dt = datetime.now().astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Central'))
DateTimeStamp=dt+ timedelta(hours=-5)